# react-bootstrap carousel hidding controls on mobile

Tags: react-bootstrap

I want to hide controls on mobile devices but there is only `true` or `false` values in component props `<Carousel controls={true}>`. Is there any way to do this with react-bootstrap? Or maybe is another simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mount of the component, you can check to see the device size. After that, assess if the `Carousel` `controls` need to be `false` (on small devices) or `true` (on big devices).

For example on functional components:

```
function App(){
  const [controlsAreVisible, setControlsAreVisible] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{

    // iPhone X width, for example
    if (window.innerWidth <= 375) {
      setControlsAreVisible(false)
    }

    // you can also set up event listeners here for "resize" for full responsiveness

  }, [])

  return(
    <Carousel controls={controlsAreVisible}>
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: May I  ask you to have a look at a react-bootstrap related question here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359611/reactjs-building-a-dynamic-horizontal-menu-with-dropdown-items-in-react-bootstr?noredirect=1#comment113807856_64359611 ?