# ReactJS- building a dynamic horizontal menu with dropdown items in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a page with a horizontal menu of categories and subcategories to be populated with database data using [react](https://reactjs.org/) and [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

The database table (namely `levels` ) has the following structure:

```
id | level_name | category |  subcategory | parent_id
```

If the row is for a `category`  then `subcategory` and `parent_id` have the value `0` and `category` contains `1`. If the row is for a subcategory then `category` column  contains `0`, `subcategory` contains `1` and `parent_id` has the `id` of the category of which this is a subcategory.

While building the horizontal menu of categories with subcategories as drop down items , I iterate over the database table and when I get a row with zero as the value in `parent_id`, I pick the `id` value and iterate over the table again to find the subcategories.

**To make  things simple, you can just concentrate on the `map` function used twice. That is where the problem occurs.**

My reactJS code is :

```
    class Header extends Component {
     constructor (props) {
     super(props)
         this.state = {
         levels_all:[],
         cat_id_found:0,
         cat_name:''
                                
          }
                          
          }
                        
                        
                        componentDidMount(prevProps) {
                        
                              //levels_all gets the value through an ajax call with axios here
                                      this.setState({
                                     levels_all: levels_all
                                  })
                        
                        }// end of componentDidMount
                        
                        
        render () {   
        
        var cat_id_found=0;
        var cat_name = '';
        
        return (
                                
        <>
                        
                            <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel'>
                              <div className='container'>
                                <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>Tasksman</Link>
                              </div>
                            </nav>
                        
                            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    
                          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                    
                          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    
                          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                              <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                        
        {
        this.state.levels_all.map( (item, idx) => ( item.parent_id == 0 ? 
                    (
        cat_id_found=item.id,
        cat_name = item.level_name
    
    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown1111" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    
    this.state.levels_all.map( (item1, idx) => 
        
        ( 
        cat_id_found == item1.id ? (
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">item1.level_name</NavDropdown.Item>
                                                        ):(
                        
                                                        )
        
))

                                                    </NavDropdown>
                        
         ) : (
                        
          )
         ))
          }
         </Nav>
                    
          </Navbar.Collapse>
         </Navbar>
                        
         <h1>THIS IS HEADER </h1>
         
        </>
          )
        }
        }
                          
export default Header
```

But I get the following error in command prompt while running the command `npm run watch`:

**Header.js: Unexpected token, expected ","**  which indicates at the `title`  of the line -

```
 <NavDropdown title="Dropdown1111" id="basic-nav-dropdown">.
```

Screenshot is here :
[image: error in command prompt]

How to get rid of the error ?

**EDIT:**

I have `ComponentDidMount` like this :

```
    componentDidMount(prevProps) {



       axios
        .post('/api/fetchLevels')
        .then(response => {
          // redirect to the homepage
          //history.push('/')

          console.log("header response = ");

          console.log(response);

            var levels_all = response.data.result;

            this.setState({
             levels_all: levels_all
          })



        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            // errors: error.response.data.errors
            errors: error
                      })
        })


}// end of ComponentDidMount
```

Comment: can you please format your code properly?

Comment: doing the formatting  now

Comment: @falinsky, formatting done ...

Comment: I don't think formatting is done properly. as soon as you'll format - I hope you will see the issue. use some editor with syntax highlighting for jsx

Comment: @falinsky, let me find one

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you are re-assigning values in your ternary operator. To fix this you can switch to an if-else statement like this:

```js
{
  this.state.levels_all.map((item, idx) => {
        if (item.parent_id == 0){
          cat_id_found=item.id
          cat_name = item.level_name
          return (
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown1111" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              {
                this.state.levels_all.map((item1, idx) => (
                  cat_id_found == item1.id ? (
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">
                      {item1.level_name}
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  ) : null))
              }
            </NavDropdown>
          )
        }
        return null
  })
}
```

Furthermore, I think it's better to use an if-else statement here because you are not returning anything in the else part so there's no point in using something so overkill and confusing.

Comment: console shows :  `Unexpected token, expected "," (` which hints at the closing cury brace after `:null`.

Comment: What is about the remaining HTML code ? Can I keep them intact ?

Comment: I forgot the remaining closing brackets for that line sorry, just edited it. As for the remaining HTML, I don't see any problem with it so you can keep them as is.

Comment: Error says , `Unexpected token, expected "," `  which hints at `</Nav>`

Comment: forgot another bracket, sorry about that

Comment: Browser console says : `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Header (created by App)`. And there is another error : `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.levels_all is undefined`

Comment: `<NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">` - in this line, I want the `href` to hold the dynamic value `"/products/"+{cat_it_found}+"/'+{item1.id}`. But writing this way does not work. What to do here ?